# Which Coroutine Dispatcher to use for running code in a loop

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my Android application, I have a usecase in which I need to run a bit of code inside a loop for as long as the app is running.

Example code:

```
  fun exampleRunCodeInLoop() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) { 
      while (true) {
        delay(5000) // Wait for 5 seconds
        // @param someCondition is just an example for the if statement
        if (someCondition == true) {
          withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // Do something on Main thread
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am confused regarding which `Dispatcher` to use for the `launch` block to get the best performance. Should I use `Default`, `IO` or just run everything on `Main`?

Comment: Dispatchers.IO is designed to be used when we block threads with longer I/O operations. For instance, when we read files, shared preferences, or calling blocking functions. This dispatcher also has a pool of threads, but it is much bigger. It is use for network operation.

If you do some CPU-intensive operations, you should run them on the Dispatchers.Default.

Comment: Its depends upon what you want to do in looping!!

Answer (score 1):

At least here's the usage I did with coroutine dispatcher.

`Dispatchers.Default` -  I usually use this when only doing CPU-intensive tasks to parallel with the current task on the main thread, it has a fixed size hardcoded to the number of available processors, because that's what makes sense for CPU-intensive tasks. Use with operation like loops, math operations,  data/image manipulations.

`Dispatchers.IO` - is designed for offloading blocking IO tasks to a shared pool of threads. Use if you still need more threads than cores if you're doing blocking IO, e.g., Database query is an IO operation or network calls

`Dispatchers.Main` - A coroutine dispatcher that is confined to the Main thread operating with UI objects. This dispatcher can be used either directly or via MainScope factory. Usually such dispatcher is single-threaded. Usually used when you are done or finished with the background task from IO or Default to forecast whatever results from operations you've done to the UI or Main Thread.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are doing IO, use the IO one
- If you are doing something CPU intensive, use the Default one

Comment: Out of those two which one would be preferable for the example code in the question? Just a simple loop that does something on Main thread when some condition is met.

Comment: For your case both are fine. Even if you run it on the UI thread (using just `viewModelScope.launch` there won't be a performance penalty since your code immediately

Comment: ...calls `delay()`).

Answer (score 1):

In your code example that does not do heavy computation or IO, there is nothing that blocks, so you can launch in Dispatchers.Main and never have to switch contexts for anything. `delay` is a suspend function, so it doesn't block. You never have to worry about which dispatcher you're on when you call a suspend function (unless someone doesn't know what they're doing and has composed a suspend function that does block).

If you were not doing everything on the Main thread, you'd be switching back and forth between dispatchers anyway so it doesn't matter which Dispatcher you launch in as long as you wrap the appropriate sections in `withContext` and use the appropriate dispatcher. A general convention is if your coroutine interacts with the UI, launch it in Main and wrap the non-main parts. This follows the convention of all the non-coroutine code in Android which is written to be called from the main thread in the majority of methods.

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatchers.Default` as it is designed to be optimal for computations, by using a shared pool of threads that contains a maximum number  of threads that is equal to the number of CPU cores

`Dispatchers.IO` in case your blocking the thread, waiting for a response without doing heavy computational logic

Comment: Out of those two which one would be preferable for the example code in the question? Just a simple loop that does something on Main thread when some condition is met.

Comment: I'd go with IO.